# Why does this ARM assemby code get stuck?

Tags: assembly, arm

```
LOOP        
                MOV     R5, #604
                LDR     R3,=Addr_IOPIN
                LDR     R3,[R3]
                B       LOOP
```

I can't seem to figure out why the code would get stuck but when it gets to the line MOV r5, #604, the debugger doesn't move on.

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't move on".
What operation are you attempting, what result are you expecting, and what result are you instead observing?

Comment: Aside from generating bus-error trap through either of the `LDR` instructions. this is an infinite loop.

Comment: There's probably some debugger issue; but the code, as currently written, is an infinite loop. And it does not do anything at all. Is this a snippet from a longer code chunk?